# How does Azure Lifecycle Management affect soft deleted items

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Let's say I have an Azure Storage Account with a blob storage. The blob storage is configured to have files archived after 14 days, while the soft delete policy is set to 30 days.

If there's a considerable amount of files in the archive and they are deleted within the 14 days while they are still in hot storage. Will the Lifecycle Management kick in and move the blobs to archive, thus applying the early deletion policy to pay the next 180 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to find the useful information from official doc, but it's so easy to test it out.

As per my test, if the blob is soft-deleted, the Lifecycle Management will not kick in for this kind of blobs(soft-deleted), and it will stay in hot tier.

Here is the screenshot of the test:

[image]